# Maximum concurrent users in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am using Spring Security 3.0 in my project and I am restricting user to have maximum one session. Configuration is given below :

```
<security:session-management>
            <security:concurrency-control error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" max-sessions="1"/>
</security:session-management>
```

I want to print the custom message(not default provided by spring) when maximum sessions are reached. Please help.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please keep this in your `messages.properties`

```
ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy.exceededAllowed=This account is already using by someone.
```

it will display "This account is already using by someone." you can give what ever you want.

Also don't forget to config `Resourcebundle`

Answer (score 2):

expired-url should be what you require.
In the configuration for spring security

```
<security:concurrent-session-control
  max-sessions="1" exception-if-maximum-exceeded="true" expired-url="/loginform.do" />
```

also add following listener in web.xml.

```
org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
```

Answer (score 1):

spring-security-3.2.0 , message.properties :

ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy.exceededAllowed = Maximum sessions of {0} for this principal exceeded