# In spring security, how to find if the session has been invalidated by multiple logins?

Tags: java, spring, concurrency, spring-security

When the user logs in with the same userid from another computer, without logging off from the first, the default behaviour is that the first session is invalidated. Now, when the user goes back to the **first computer**, I want to tell him that his session has been invalidated because he has logged on from some other computer. How can I do that ?

I have thought of two approaches :

- Allow multiple logins, and when the user logs in from the second computer, add a boolean flag to all the sessions (whose ids are obtained from the `sessionRegistry`) and when the user goes back to login from the first computer, check whether the current session has the boolean flag as true. If yes, invalidate the session, and send the user a message. This will be done in a `CustomSuccessHandler`.

**Flipside** : Its probably not possible to obtain the session object via the session id (which is all what session registry provides)

- Don't allow multiple logins, and when the user goes back to his first computer, somehow find out the reason for the session being invalidated. If its invalidated because of multiple logins, display the proper message.

**Flipside** : It doesn't seem possible to add invalidation reasons while invalidating a session, and I don't know how to access this information (if it exists) from the first computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't allow multiple logins. You can easily achieve this using spring security.

Add `concurrent-session-control` to spring security.

```
<concurrent-session-control max-sessions="1" exception-if-maximum-exceeded="false" expired-url="/jsp/invalidate.do"/> 
//you can also set expired-url to your custom invalidate page rather than create a mapping
```

Create custom requestMapping for invalidate user.

```
@RequestMapping( value = "/invalidate.do", method = RequestMethod.GET )
    public String invalidate(HttpServletRequest request)
    {
       request.setAttribute("invalidate",true);
       return "login";
    }
```

Then your login page

```
<c:if test="${not empty invalidate}">
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("You have been Logged Out. Someone signed in using your account.");
</script>
</script>
```

Another way is to set your `error-if-maximum-exceed` to `true`,so it will flag error if user tries to login into another session.

```
<security:session-management>
            <security:concurrency-control error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" max-sessions="1"/>
</security:session-management>
```

Then create a custom message in your message.properties

```
ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy.exceededAllowed=You have been Logged Out. Someone signed in using your account.
```

Hope it helps.

Links:
http://codehustler.org/blog/spring-security-tutorial-form-login/
[Maximum concurrent users in Spring Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678275/maximum-concurrent-users-in-spring-security)