# cannot override spring security error messages

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

Good day SO people!

I have a question regarding custom spring security error messages. I've done some searching on how to do this and came up with putting the snippet below in my `root-context.xml`

```
    <!-- override spring security messages -->
    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">  
        <property name="basenames">  
            <list>
                <value>mymessages</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

and creating a properties file named `mymessages.properties` in `WEB-INF\classes\` folder.

I don't know if anyone here has encountered the same problem but I'm giving this a shot. You see I was able to override the message for the "Bad Credentials" message.

```
AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials=Invalid username or password.
```

Now, I wanted to override the message for maximum allowable sessions which uses the key

```
ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy.exceededAllowed=Maximum sessions of {0} for this principal exceeded
```

but for some reason when I change the value of the key, it is not being reflected.

Anybody who has the same situation? Thanks in advance!

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678275/maximum-concurrent-users-in-spring-security

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem, I looked throught the spring code to see what message they use and it is different:

As you said, the messages say:

```
ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy.exceededAllowed
```

However, in the code [ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/session/ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy.html) the message they use is different to the one in messages.properties

```
protected void allowableSessionsExceeded(List<SessionInformation> sessions,
        int allowableSessions, SessionRegistry registry)
        throws SessionAuthenticationException {
    if (exceptionIfMaximumExceeded || (sessions == null)) {
        throw new SessionAuthenticationException(messages.getMessage(
                "ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy.exceededAllowed",
                new Object[] { Integer.valueOf(allowableSessions) },
                "Maximum sessions of {0} for this principal exceeded"));
    }
```

So in summary, override using this:

```
ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy.exceededAllowed
```

instead of this:

```
ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy.exceededAllowed
```

Hope someone finds it helpful

Comment: this is working for me: ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy.exceededAllowed=You are already login from different device or browser.